# sed replacing a string with itself and a new line

Tags: bash, sed, replace, newlines

I have the following string multiple times in a html file

```
<br> <h4 id=...
```

Now, I know sed might not be perfect for html editing, but could tell me how can I 
replace `br> <h4 id` 
with `br>\n <h4 id` (where '\n' is the new line; there is a single space between `<br>` and `<h4...`)?

I'd tried `sed 's/br> <h4 id/br> \n<h4 id/g' report.html` but it doesn't do the trick. There are other questions regarding sed and new line replacement, on this subject on this stackexchange, but they don't work for my case. Thank you!

**Update:** I'm running from a windows machine with Visual Studio Code bash terminal and (Git) Bash (which is some sort of MINGW64)

Comment: HOW doesn't it do the trick (for you)? For me, it works.

Comment: sorry guys, this is really embarrassing and weird: I'm on Windows machine and I'm running the bash from the visual studio code (I also tried from Git Bash available on this machine) ... both the above code and the one from Stefane Chazelas dont't work ... I'll update the initial post

Comment: `sed` has nothing to do with `bash`. In which way is your environment less *special* than `MacOS`?

Comment: Windows is mostly off-topic here. What's visual studio code? It looks like it's some sort of Windows text editor. Why would it have anything to do with a Unix shell such as bash, let alone `sed`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ... man I don't know; I can only tell you I can run some linux commands and they work; in the script I'm working on, there is another sed which works (removing a lot of unnecessary things from the html file).

Comment: I'd just checked all 3 solutions (mine, 1st @StéphaneChazelas and @schrodigerscatcuriosity), appending `> report2.html` (outputing to another file) and they all work (i.e. the report2.html contains these replacements)

Answer (score 2):

A newline in the replacement part of the `s` `sed` command is expressed portably with `\` followed by a newline character, so:

```
sed 's/br> <h4 id/br>\
<h4 id/g' report.html
```

Or:

```
sed 's/\(br>\) \(<h4 id\)/\1\
\2/g' report.html
```

Some `sed` implementations allow `\n` there as well, but it's a non-standard extension.

With a few `sh` implementation (and it's likely going to be made standard in the next major version of the POSIX standard), you can use the `$'...'` form of quotes (initially from ksh93) where `\n` is expanded to a newline character (and `\\` to a backslash character). So with those, you could do:

```
sed $'s/\(br>\) \(<h4 id\)/\1\\\n\2/g' report.html
```

That same next version of the standard will also introduce the `-E` option of `sed` (from BSD `sed`) to enable *extended* regular expressions there allowing you to do:

```
sed -E $'s/(br>) (<h4 id)/\1\\\n\2/g' report.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sed 's/br>[[:blank:]]*<h4 id/br> \n<h4 id/g'
```

It may be that there are more than one space between `br>` and `<h4` (or none).